# disable warning from `drop table if exists`

Tags: postgresql

When I `DROP` a table with the `IF EXISTS` clause (in PostgreSQL 11.x), it issues a warning as follows:

```
=> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tt;

NOTICE:  table "tt" does not exist, skipping
```

Sometimes, I do expect that certain tables to not exist, and don't want to see many warnings like these in the output of a batch processing function/script.

Is there a way to disable this type of warning altogether?

Answer (score 15):

The "warning" is in fact a "notice". You can disable the display of those notices trough the property `client_min_messages`  which controls the minimum level of messages returned to the client.

To only display warnings, but not notices use:

```
set client_min_messages = warning;
```

Note that this will disable **all** notices, including those sent through `raise notice` from e.g. a PL/pgSQL function.

Comment: @tinlyx maybe take a moment to accept this answer

Comment: reference :
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html

Comment: To permanently apply the default to a given DB, execute `alter database dbname set client_min_messages=warning;`